# Using Laravel 5.4 pusher

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am having trouble making pusher work . I have followed the documentation but I donot know the problem is.. The console returns null.

```
public function broadcastOn()
{

    return new PrivateChannel('my-channel');
}
```

and here is my js for pusher.

```
 <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function () {



    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
```

var pusher = new Pusher('6049410e84e42d918b14', {
            encrypted: true
        });

```
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');

    channel.bind('\Dms\Events\NewNotification', addMessage);

    function addMessage(data) {
        var listItem = $("<li class='list-group-item'></li>");
        listItem.html(data.message);
        $('#messages').prepend(listItem);

        console.log(data.message)
    }

})()
```

Above is all the code that I have used as test. Please anyone who have done this assist. Laravel 5.4 is what am using right now.
 Below is the error code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne2yA.png)

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.4, Private channels have a prefix of `private-` added to it. So try changing this:

```
 var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
```

to this:

```
 var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-my-channel');
```

Secondly, check your string, you will need to escape backslashes. So `'\Dms\Events\NewNotification'` should be this: `'\\Dms\\Events\\NewNotification'`

Finally, I would recommend using Laravel Echo as it makes things really easy to work with Pusher and Laravel. With Echo, these two lines of code:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');

channel.bind('\Dms\Events\NewNotification', addMessage);
```

Will look like this:

```
Echo.private('my-channel')
    .listen('\\Dms\\Events\\NewNotification', addMessage);
```

Notice you don't have to write the prefix `private-` anymore.

Comment: Thanks but now I have this kind of error Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404
warn @ pusher.min.js:8
r.onreadystatechange @ pusher.min.js:8
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : No callbacks on private-test for pusher:subscription_error

Comment: @philipNjuguna Hmm, as this is a different error now, I suggest you ask a new StackOverflow question so people can answer for that error. If my current answer has solved the issue in your original question, I hope you can mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!